# Maintain 1:1 aspect ratio of div based on inner child img element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to maintain a 1:1 aspect ratio of div. The aspect ratio must be maintain even when the browser window is resized. The width and height must be equal of div must be matched to image resolution.
How to do this ? I am new to css hence looking for for any help.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="blackoverlay"></div>
<img src="someimage"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the image itself has 1:1 ratio? If yes, then what is the problem?

Comment: Could you add more code and some explanation. What is blackoverlay? How are the initial dimensions of the square defined? (by the image itself, with some maximum, as a % of viewport size, by dimensions of wrapper or....?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i got it right you want the `.blackoverlay` element to overlay your image in `.wrapper` element.

The the easient approach will be to set `.blackoverlay` to `position: absolute` in order to fit parent element.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative; /* prevent position absolute element from exceding this element */
  display: inline-block; /* prevent stretching element to full width like display: block does */
}

.wrapper .blackoverlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="blackoverlay"></div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="150x150"/>
</div>
```